# Change units and values of data frame

Tags: r, match, units-of-measurement

I have a data frame with compounds concentrations and their target value in water. 
For some compounds the registered values have different units than their maximum value.

I would like to convert the target to the same units of the value. 
So for example I have this:

```
  Value    Dimension  Target   Unit
A  0.001    ug/L       12     ng/L
B  0.1      ug/L       1      ug/L
C  0.25     ug/L       1      ng/L
```

I want to get:

```
   Value    Dimension  Target   Unit
A  0.001    ug/L       0.012     ug/L
B  0.1      ug/L       1         ug/L
C  0.25     ug/L       0.001     ug/L
```

1ng/L = 1000 ug/L

How can I do this in R?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested `ifelse` statement to catch all 3 scenarios (same, from `ng` to `ug` and from `ug` to `ng`)

```
ifelse(df$Dimension == df$Unit, df$Target, 
       ifelse(df$Dimension != df$Unit & grepl('ug', df$Dimension), df$Target / 1000, 
                                                                        df$Target * 1000))

#[1] 0.012 1.000 0.001
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ifelse`. If `dat` is the data.frame you provided, then something like this should work:

```
dat[, "Target"] <- ifelse(dat[,"Unit"]=="ng/L", dat[,"Target"]/1000, dat[,"Target"])
```

If you have more than two different units, you would need to nest the `ifelse` call or call `ifelse` consecutively.

Note that `ifelse` is a vectorized version of `if`, and handles the whole column at once.